# How to call setter to add my string to list of parent with using xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a segment view for iOS and Android with using Xamarin form.

It's working fine if I generate it from code. 
But I want to generate it from xaml.

like this.

```
<local:Segment>
    <local:Segmentbutton text="boy">
    <local:Segmentbutton text="girl">
<local:Segment>
```

In my Segment class, it generates buttons and add to lists to control them.

When I generate My Segment with code, looks like this.

```
List<String> buttonTexts = new List<String>();
buttonTexts.Add ("B");
buttonTexts.Add ("G");

segment = new AXSegment (buttonTexts, 50, Color.FromHex ("#000000"), AppConstants.GlobalColor, Color.FromHex ("#EEEEEE"));
segment.buttonCallback = SexSegmentButtonChanged;
segment.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

What docs should I look to do it in xaml?

I looked "BindableProperty" or many thins but could not find yet. 
I just want trigger SETTER when

```
<local:Segmentbutton text="boy">
```

so that I just generate button and add it to my list in MySegment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentPropertyAttribute` is the keyword. You have to create:

**Segment**

Nothing special here, just a `Element` with a `Text` property.

```cs
public class Segment : Element
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Segment, string>(p => p.Text, string.Empty);

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**SegmentedView**

Inherits from `View`.  The attribute `ContentProperty` tells the Xaml-Interpreter/Compiler to stuff every child node into the property called `Segments`.

```cs
[ContentProperty("Segments")]
public class SegmentedView : View
{
    private readonly IList<Segment> _segments = new List<Segment>();

    public IList<Segment> Segments
    {
        get { return _segments; }
    }
}
```

**SegmentedViewRender**

Your custom renderer inherits from a renderer of your choice. `Android.Views.View` is the type of the native control. You have to change it.

```cs
public class SegmentedViewRender : ViewRenderer<SegmentedView, Android.Views.View>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // segments are in: this.Element.Segments
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:SegmentedView>
    <local:Segment Text="Bengal"></local:Segment>
    <local:Segment Text="Siam"></local:Segment>
    <local:Segment Text="Maine Coon"></local:Segment>
</local:SegmentedView>
```

Comment: Fantastic.. Thank you so much. it works like a charm.

Comment: I want to ask one more question. Where can I detect the time that Segment's added as member of that array? Because I want to add some code in it.

Comment: If you want this, you have to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` then you can register to the `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Oh Great. Thanks again. I was thinking there is something like that.

Comment: As you said, [ContentProperty("Segments")] was the key.

Comment: and why you had to use 'BindableProperty'? I tested it and it works when I only wrote setter and getter of Text string. If it wouldn't be changed in a future. it's enough?